# Jenkins Host key verification failed to deploy

Tags: jenkins, ssh, deployment

i have project jenkins to deploy to my remote server, my local machine and my remote server was connected with ssh but when i try to build job on jenkins, i am getting error like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qioWH.png)

Comment: Please post TEXT of text-based error messages, [not pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Login on your jenkins and then try to connect manually on the command line with ssh from jenkins to the remote server. Then approve the host key of the remote system. Run again your job. Then I think everything should be fine.